# Why would you use String.Equals over ==?

Tags: c#, string, equals

I recently was introduced to a large codebase and noticed all string comparisons are done using `String.Equals()` instead of `==`

What's the reason for this, do you think?

Comment: Re : Duplicate closure - note that this question is specifically for string, whereas the accepted answer in the referenced duplicate refers to the general case of object. This is significantly different in .Net vs Java as `==` can be used to compare string contents in C#.

Comment: `Equals` may be preferred since the appearance of the _null-propagation operator_, because you may return `false` also in case of both string `null`, in a very concise way; like this:
`if(firstString?.Equals(secondString) ?? false)`

Answer (score 415):

It's entirely likely that a large portion of the developer base comes from a Java background where using `==` to compare strings is wrong and doesn't work.

In C# there's no (practical) difference (for strings) as long as they are typed as `string`.

If they are typed as `object` or `T` then see other answers here that talk about generic methods or operator overloading as there you definitely want to use the `Equals` method.

Comment: Not as far as the values returned goes. `.Equals` does offer more options but `str1.Equals(str2)` is the same as `str1 == str2` as far as what you get as a result. I do believe they use different methods for determining the equality as Jon Skeets quote that Blaenk brings up would indicate, but they give the same values.

Comment: Functionality wise they are the same, but computationally there are slight differences.

Comment: @Yuriy Perhaps you could elaborate or provide a link on the differences?

Comment: From Blaenk's answer: http://dotnetperls.com/string-equals-compare

Comment: Basically, it boils down to one less null check (since you don't have to check whether `this` is null or not)

Comment: Isn't string.Equals considered a MSFT best practice (via FxCop?)

Comment: There is a big difference. If one of the strings are null, then .Equals will throw an exception.

Comment: @Mas: The only exception ever thrown by `.Equals` is a null reference exception if you try to call it on an object that is null, ie. `string str1 = null; str1.Equals()`. This isn't an issue with `Equals()`, that happens with any function and should be self-evident. The actual functionality of the two comparisons is always exactly the same given the same inputs.

Comment: @Matthew: Exactly my point, why risk a NullReferenceException? I would always use `a == b` instead of `a.Equals(b)`. Am I off on this?

Comment: @Mas: In C#, you'd be totally spot on. But as I said in my answer, people from other backgrounds may be used to other things because the language they are most familiar with doesn't work quite the same way.

Comment: The link above doesn't work any longer, but this one does: http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-equals

Comment: @MatthewScharley There is practical difference between `string.Equals and ==`

Comment: I came across an example in the last 5 mins where == and string.Equals do NOT produce the same result.  The equality check evaluated false with == and true with string.Equals.  Both strings are string properties of an object created from reading an XML file (using System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer).  They are identical in the XML.  I don't currently have an explanation, but thought it worth mentioning.  I guess it's some kind of reference issue.

Comment: @Nande, Sounds like Xamarin/mono is buggy then. In .NET, String == String is supposed to use value equality. Note, this *only* works if both instances are instances of `string`! `(object)"a" == (object)"a"` will use `object`s equality operator which will use reference equality and return false in a non-trivial example (in this exact case the compiler will use the same memory for both equivalent compile-time constants). See vikas's answer below.

Comment: [It is best to avoid using the == and != operators when you compare strings.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165449.aspx)

Comment: @Mas doesn't the `string.==` operator does the same thing internally as `string.Equals`?

Comment: @Matthew "why risk a NullPointerException?" - Well, because often, if I'm at the point of comparing Strings, I'm going to use one or both of them and expect neither to be null, and I want to know as soon as possible if one is null so as not to continue normal execution under undefined conditions. The NullPointerException wasn't created to be evil, it exists as a safeguard for that situation. There are certainly situations where you don't care if a String is null, but I don't think it makes much sense to have a blanket conception that whatever approach doesn't throw the exception is best.

Comment: @tradeJmark if you are comparing two 'string's where one of them is null for equality then I don't want to wrap my comparison in a try/catch just to handle one of the objects being null. Exceptions aren't evil, they're just damned annoying when all I'm trying to do is a comparison inside an if statement.

Comment: @Matthew Well, sure, like I said, there are situations where you don't care if a String is null. I would have guessed it's much more common for people to deal with empty strings than to allow them to be null during normal program operation, but that can just be a decision of style. I was just trying to give an answer to why one would "risk" a NullPointerException, I didn't mean it always has to be done my way.

Comment: I guess I would tend to specifically make my program use empty Strings for normal input and intentionally reserve null Strings for errors, just so I can always tell what's good data and what's bad, but that doesn't have to be how you do it, there are other ways.

Comment: @tradeJmark you still risk missing a null string anyway - the one you pass in as the argument to `Equals()`. Don't rely on NullPointerException's to catch your nulls - you should be checking if you suspect a null is possible.

Comment: @Mas It will only throw an exception if the string on which you call `.Equals()` is null. This is why you should/could use `string.Equals()` instead of `myString.Equals()`.

Comment: Java string '==' is "broken" in the exact same way the .NET string 'ReferenceEquals' is "broken".  Basically, for any language that uses string interning (most, I think), you simply can never rely on string identity equality to be useful or meaningful.

Answer (score 137):

**There is practical difference between `string.Equals` and `==`**

```
bool result = false;

object obj = "String";    
string str2 = "String";
string str3 = typeof(string).Name;
string str4 = "String";
object obj2 = str3;

// Comparision between object obj and string str2 -- Com 1
result = string.Equals(obj, str2);// true
result = String.ReferenceEquals(obj, str2); // true
result = (obj == str2);// true

// Comparision between object obj and string str3 -- Com 2
result = string.Equals(obj, str3);// true
result = String.ReferenceEquals(obj, str3); // false
result = (obj == str3);// false

// Comparision between object obj and string str4 -- Com 3
result = string.Equals(obj, str4);// true
result = String.ReferenceEquals(obj, str4); // true
result = (obj == str4);// true

// Comparision between string str2 and string str3 -- Com 4
result = string.Equals(str2, str3);// true
result = String.ReferenceEquals(str2, str3); // false
result = (str2 == str3);// true

// Comparision between string str2 and string str4 -- Com 5
result = string.Equals(str2, str4);// true
result = String.ReferenceEquals(str2, str4); // true
result = (str2 == str4);// true

// Comparision between string str3 and string str4 -- Com 6
result = string.Equals(str3, str4);// true
result = String.ReferenceEquals(str3, str4); // false
result = (str3 == str4);// true

// Comparision between object obj and object obj2 -- Com 7
result = String.Equals(obj, obj2);// true
result = String.ReferenceEquals(obj, obj2); // false
result = (obj == obj2);// false
```

**Adding Watch**

```
obj     "String" {1#}   object {string}
str2    "String" {1#}   string
str3    "String" {5#}   string
str4    "String" {1#}   string
obj2    "String" {5#}   object {string}
```

Now look at `{1#}` and `{5#}`

`obj`, `str2`, `str4` and `obj2` references are same.

`obj` and `obj2` are `object type` and others are `string type`

**[Conclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104784/behavior-of-string-equals-and)**:

1. **com1**: result = (obj == str2);// true

   - compares `object` and `string` so performs a reference equality check
   - obj and str2 point to the same reference so the result is true
2. **com2**: result = (obj == str3);// false

   - compares `object` and `string` so performs a reference equality check
   - obj and str3 point to the different references so the result is false
3. **com3**: result = (obj == str4);// true

   - compares `object` and `string` so performs a reference equality check
   - obj and str4 point to the same reference so the result is true
4. **com4**: result = (str2 == str3);// true

   - compares `string` and `string` so performs a string value check
   - str2 and str3 are both "String" so the result is true
5. **com5**: result = (str2 == str4);// true

   - compares `string` and `string` so performs a string value check
   - str2 and str4 are both "String" so the result is true
6. **com6**: result = (str3 == str4);// true

   - compares `string` and `string` so performs a string value check
   - str3 and str4 are both "String" so the result is true
7. **com7**: result = (obj == obj2);// false
    - compares `object` and `object` so performs a reference equality check
        - obj and obj2 point to the different references so the result is false

Comment: Simple explanation for all cases above: `string.Equals(object, object)` **is** `object.Equals(object, object)` which calls `Equals` on the first argument, unlike `==` operator, which, unless overloaded, calls `ReferenceEquals`.

Comment: I believe that the reason that `"String"` and `typeof(string).Name` are different references is that the former, as a compile-time constant, is [interned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx), whereas the latter, as a run-time value, is not.

Comment: Why do you use camelCase `string` for `Equals` but CapCase `String` for `ReferenceEquals`?

Comment: @AlexMcMillan, I could use `string` instead `String` as `string` is just alias of `System.String`

Comment: @vikas that's my point.. I was wondering if you had a specific reason, or if it was just an inconsistency.

Comment: re: "ComX". Back in the bad old days of DOS, I received some data in which someone had named the file "com3" ("Com" for "community" in this case, not "comparison")..Of course when trying to access the file, the OS thought it was a com port, with interesting results. 30 years later, but I refrain from naming ''anything'' "com-whatever" unless it really is a com port.

Comment: In the case where you are comparing an `object` to a `string`, I'm not sure it's a practical comparison, since if you already know the value is a string in order to consider `string.Equals()` an alternative, you should be using a variable of the appropriate type. You now also have the option of using `obj is "String"`, but not `obj is obj2`, however if you can't narrow down the type from `object`, there's really no point in testing for equality unless you want to use serialization or maybe exhaustive type tests.

Answer (score 101):

There is one **subtle but very important difference** between == and the String.Equals methods:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CheckEquality("a", "a");
        Console.WriteLine("----------");
        CheckEquality("a", "ba".Substring(1));
    }

    static void CheckEquality<T>(T value1, T value2) where T : class
    {
        Console.WriteLine("value1: {0}", value1);
        Console.WriteLine("value2: {0}", value2);

        Console.WriteLine("value1 == value2:      {0}", value1 == value2);
        Console.WriteLine("value1.Equals(value2): {0}", value1.Equals(value2));

        if (typeof(T).IsEquivalentTo(typeof(string)))
        {
            string string1 = (string)(object)value1;
            string string2 = (string)(object)value2;
            Console.WriteLine("string1 == string2:    {0}", string1 == string2);
        }
    }
}
```

Produces this output:

> ```
> value1: a
> value2: a
> value1 == value2:      True
> value1.Equals(value2): True
> string1 == string2:    True
> ----------
> value1: a
> value2: a
> value1 == value2:      False
> value1.Equals(value2): True
> string1 == string2:    True
> ```

You can see that the == operator is returning *false* to two obviously equal strings. Why? Because the == operator in use in the generic method is resolved to be the op_equal method as defined by System.Object (the only guarantee of T the method has at compile time), which means that it's reference equality instead of value equality.

When you have two values typed as System.String explicitly, then == has a value-equality semantic because the compiler resolves the == to System.String.op_equal instead of System.Object.op_equal.

So to play it safe, I almost always use String.Equals instead to that I always get the value equality semantics I want.

And to avoid NullReferenceExceptions if one of the values is null, I always use the *static* String.Equals method:

```
bool true = String.Equals("a", "ba".Substring(1));
```

Comment: A related gotcha occurs with code that returns things of type `Object`.  If `var myItem=GetItem()` reads an `Object` from the database, the expressions `"Hi".Equals(myItem)`, `myItem.Equals("Hi")`, and `Object.Equals("Hi", myItem)` will all return `True` if the returned object is a `string` with two characters "Hi", but `myItem == "Hi"` or `"Hi" == myItem` will test reference equality.  The "Option Strict On" dialect of VB.NET is better in that regard.  Its "=" operator tests either tests value equality or won't compile; for a reference-equality check, one uses the "Is" operator.

Comment: @AndrewArnott If I execute `"a" == "ab".Substring(0, 1)` on http://csharppad.com I get back `true`. Same if I use `String` objects. Explanation?

Comment: Because in your example, the compiler knows to invoke the `System.String` overload of the `==` operator. The case you have to be cautious of is when the compiler *doesn't* know what type it is, such as when the compared expressions are typed as `T` or `System.Object`.

Comment: @AndrewArnott Could you elaborate on why `.Substring()` causes different behavior? As it returns a `string`, not a `string` wrapped in an `object`, why does it not have the same behavior as the first check? To me, it seems like both should have the exact same output. It's guaranteed to be a string comparison in the second example, just as it is in the first.

Comment: @Rob The comparison is done in a generic method that does *not* know when it is compiled that it will be doing a string comparison. Therefore the `==` operator used in the generic method is an `object ==` operator rather than a `string==` operator. The reason `.Substring(1)` produces a different result is that the method creates a *new* string object rather than possibly reusing another one that already has the same value. Thus as the two strings with equivalent values but different objects are seen as different by the generic method.

Comment: @AndrewArnott I think the main reason is that,It is about string interning.At the first call to CheckEquality("a", "a"); "a" and "a"  compile-time constant, is interned, whereas the latter, as a run-time value, is not.

Answer (score 50):

`String.Equals` does offer overloads to handle casing and culture-aware comparison.  If your code doesn't make use of these, the devs may just be used to Java, where (as Matthew says), you must use the .Equals method to do content comparisons.

Comment: This should get much higher, as culture-aware (and explicit case sensitivity) comparisons are better practive - e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices-strings#recommendations_for_string_usage

Comment: Agree with @Bartosz! Making your intent clear is Microsoft best practice.Using `==` does not explicitly tell the reader what is expected to happen with regard to case-sensitivity and culture.

Answer (score 37):

Both methods do the same *functionally* - they compare **values**.
As is written on MSDN:

- About `String.Equals` method - Determines whether this instance and
  another specified String object have the same value. ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/858x0yyx.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/362314fe.aspx))
- About `==` - Although string is a reference type, the equality operators (`==` and
  `!=`) are defined to compare the values of string objects, not
  references. This makes testing for string equality more intuitive. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/362314fe.aspx)

But if one of your string instances is null, these methods are working differently:

```
string x = null;
string y = "qq";
if (x == y) // returns false
    MessageBox.Show("true");
else
    MessageBox.Show("false");

if (x.Equals(y)) // returns System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. - because x is null !!!
    MessageBox.Show("true");
else
    MessageBox.Show("false");
```

Answer (score 17):

There's a writeup on [this article](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-equals) which you might find to be interesting, with some quotes from Jon Skeet. It seems like the use is pretty much the same.

> Jon Skeet states that the performance of instance Equals "is slightly better when the strings are short—as the strings increase in length, that difference becomes completely insignificant."

Comment: What exactly qualifies as a "short" string?

Comment: @AndHeCodedIt Depends on the speed of your system I presume. Run a benchmark.

Answer (score 8):

I want to add that there is another difference. It is related to what Andrew posts.

It is also related to a VERY annoying to find bug in our software. See the following simplified example (I also omitted the null check).

```
public const int SPECIAL_NUMBER = 213;

public bool IsSpecialNumberEntered(string numberTextBoxTextValue)
{
    return numberTextBoxTextValue.Equals(SPECIAL_NUMBER)
}
```

This will compile and always return `false`. While the following will give a compile error:

```
public const int SPECIAL_NUMBER = 213;

public bool IsSpecialNumberEntered(string numberTextBoxTextValue)
{
    return (numberTextBoxTextValue == SPECIAL_NUMBER);
}
```

We have had to solve a similar problem where someone compared enums of different type using `Equals`. You are going to read over this MANY times before realising it is the cause of the bug. Especially if the definition of `SPECIAL_NUMBER` is not near the problem area.

This is why I am really against the use of Equals in situations where is it not necessary. You lose a little bit of type-safety.

Comment: that is why it is good to use the static string.Equals method always with the StringComparison argument - that overload will produce a compile error when trying to compare strings and integers

Comment: I wish method and operator parameters could have attributes (and that `Equals` and `ReferenceEquals` had always used them) that would disallow implicit conversions, upcasts, boxing conversions, or combinations of the above.  I also wish some operator other than `==` had been used for reference equality.  Having `Equals` and `==` define equivalence relations with all argument types where they compile would be more helpful than having them compile in cases that do not yield equivalence relations.

Answer (score 6):

I've just been banging my head against a wall trying to solve a bug because I read this page and concluded there was no meaningful difference when in practice there is so I'll post this link here in case anyone else finds they get different results out of == and equals.

[Object == equality fails, but .Equals succeeds. Does this make sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775283/object-equality-fails-but-equals-succeeds-does-this-make-sense)

```
string a = "x";
string b = new String(new []{'x'});

Console.WriteLine("x == x " + (a == b));//True
Console.WriteLine("object x == x " + ((object)a == (object)b));//False
Console.WriteLine("x equals x " + (a.Equals(b)));//True
Console.WriteLine("object x equals x " + (((object)a).Equals((object)b)));//True
```

Comment: As I understand it, the second equality check fails as `Object == Object` resolves to `System.Object.ReferenceEquals` and `a` and `b` are two different objects in memory. The remainder compare the values of the string objects. Even the last comparison, which seems to call `.Equals` for the `Object` type object, as it is implemented as a `virtual` method, it defaults to calling `String.Equals`.