# '==' vs string.equals c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, equals-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: String.Equals vs. ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659097/c-string-equals-vs)

Hi to all.

Some time someone told me that you should never compare strings with == and that you should use string.equals(), but it refers to java.

¿What is the diference beteen == and string.equals in .NET c#?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`string == string` is entirely the same as `String.Equals`. This is the exact code (from Reflector):

```
public static bool operator ==(string a, string b)
{
    return Equals(a, b); // Is String.Equals as this method is inside String
}
```

Comment: So, can I say that == is less performance than equals?

Comment: @Daniel G. R. No, small methods will be inlined by the just-in-time compiler so don't worry about that :) And if there is a VERY small time increase in the JIT-compiling itself, you shouldn't worry about that ;)

Answer (score 3):

In C# there is no difference as the operator `==` and `!=` have been overloaded in string type to call `equals()`. See this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664728%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

== actually ends up executing String.Equals on Strings.

You *can* specify a StringComparision when you use String.Equals....

Example:

```
MyString.Equals("TestString", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Mostly, I consider it a coding preference.  Use whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

The `==` operator calls the `String.Equals` method. So at best you're saving a method call. Decompiled code:

```
public static bool operator ==(string a, string b)
{
  return string.Equals(a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-difference-between-and-equals) for a better description. As one answer stated

> > When == is used on an object type, it'll resolve to
> >     System.Object.ReferenceEquals.
>
> Equals is just a virtual method and
>   behaves as such, so the overridden
>   version will be used (which, for
>   string type compares the contents).

Answer (score 0):

no difference, it's just an operator overload. for strings it's internally the same thing. 
however, you don't want to get in a habit of using == for comparing objects and that's why it's not recommended to use it for strings as well.

Answer (score 0):

In C# there's no difference for strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont care about the string's case and dont worry about cultural awarenes then it's the same...