# why can't I populate the sub lists

Tags: c#, list

Now I'm having a problem of populating some sub lists. I have a main list called "list" of type FileInfo with thousands of files. What I want to do is to split this main list into several sub lists, each of which contains a pack of files with the same name. I did sth like this:

```
var File = list;
string[] foldername = Names.Distinct().ToArray();
List<TreeNode> N1 = new List<TreeNode>();
List<FileInfo>[] sublist = new List<FileInfo>[foldername.Length];

for (int j = 0; j < foldername.Length; j++)
{
    N1.Add(clicked.Nodes.Add(foldername[j]));
    foreach (FileInfo file in File)
    {
        if (file.Name== N1[j].Name)
                sublist[j].Add(file);
    }
}
```

For example the foldername array has 7 elements, so I want to have 7 sublists. Files included in each sublist have the same name with the tree node N1[j]. 
The result, however, is that the

```
sublist[j].Add(file)
```

isn't excuted at all, and every sublist is null. I have no idea what's wrong. Anybody got any idea? Thank you

Comment: can I suggest you do `Names.GroupBy(x => x).ToList()`? (note this will still be strings and not `FileInfo`)

Comment: @jcraffael Are you sure you `File` names are matching the `Names` names? I think the `if (file.Name== N1[j].Name)` is never evaluated to `true`.

Comment: @jcraffael What is stored in N1? If they contain the filenames with the pathnames included, then the strings won't be the same. And have you tried file.Name.Equals(N1[j].Name) instead of == ?

Comment: @Dennis_E On the .NET String type, `Equals` is the same as `==` except with the latter you don't have to do explicit null protection because you aren't actually invoking a method on the instance. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5796219/486504)

Comment: @Maarten Well not exactly, it's in fact file.Name.Substring(0,4) shall equal to N1[j].Name. In my code it's like this. Here I just want to simplfy the code.

Comment: @jcraffael Will the if statement `if (file.Name== N1[j].Name)` then ever evaluate to `true` ? I think not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
List<FileInfo>[] sublist = new List<FileInfo>[foldername.Length];
```

doesn't actually create an array with empty lists, it creates an array with NULL references. I think you should create an instance of an empty list, and store it in the array.

Comment: Exactly! So my last sentence "sublist[j].Add(file)" is for populating them!

Comment: Small mistake on my part, you are creating an array with NULL references. I think you should create empty list instances, and set store them in the array.

Comment: Maybe you are right. But that means I shall creat 7 times "List<FileInfo>sublist = new List<FileInfo>()" and store them in an array like "List<File>[]Sublist={sublist1, sublist2....sublist7}"? If so, that's really unconvenient especially when the length of array is huge

Comment: @jcraffael `for (int j = 0; j < foldername.Length; j++)
{ sublist[j] = new List<FileInfo>(); ...`

Comment: Your code has two inputs: `list` and `Names`. `list` is a list/enumerable of `FileInfo`'s, and `Names` is a list of strings. Do they contain the same data?

Comment: ok done! You are right about it. With Tzah's suggestion I made it. Thanks you very much