# How to count number of Excel files from a folder using c#?

Tags: c#

I need to count the number of excel files,pdf files from a directory.

I have Counted the total number of files from a directory using

```
 System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"D:\");
 int count = dir.GetFiles().Length;
```

Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a LINQ solution.

```
var extensions = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
    ".xls",
    ".xlsx",
    ".pdf",
};
var baseDir = @"D:\";
var count = Directory.EnumerateFiles(baseDir)
                     .Count(filename =>
                                extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(filename)));
```

Comment: +1 nice use of EnumerateFiles. Also "why wouldn't it ever be possible" made me smile.

Comment: @Conrad: Yeah, it's just one of those things that always gets to me.  It always strikes a nerve when I hear the words, "is it possible?" when there are tools we use every day that does "the impossible."  But that part is gone now.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Use SearchPattern in `GetFiles` method.

```
dir.GetFiles("*.XLS");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int count = 0;
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\"))
{
    if (file.EndsWith(".pdf") || file.EndsWith(".xls"))
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var count = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\")
               .Count(p => Path.GetExtension(p) == ".xls");
```

Comment: can you compare strings like that? Shouldn't be .Equals()?

Comment: @surfen: if it were Java it would need to be `.equals()`; but in C# it doesn't matter.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659097/c-string-equals-vs

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] excelFiles=Directory.GetFiles("C:\\", "*.xls");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = Directory.GetFiles(path).Count(f =>(f.EndsWith(".xls") || f.EndsWith(".xlsx")));
```

Answer (score 0):

simple

```
int count = dir.GetFiles("*.txt").Length + dir.GetFiles("*.pdf").Length
```