# How to filter a linq to sql query by using textbox input

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, filter

Here is my code:

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //**************************************
        int aa = textBox1.Text.Length;

        var qry = (from p in dc.Products
                   where p.ProductName.Substring(aa) == textBox1.Text.Trim()
                   select p).ToList();
        productDataGridView.DataSource = qry;
    }
```

When I enter a letter in the textbox the datagrid become empty

Comment: Use `p.ProductName.Contains(textBox1.Text.Trim())` instead of `p.ProductName.Substring(aa) == textBox1.Text.Trim()`

Comment: @Chandu p.ProductName.Contains(textBox1.Text.Trim()) mean that the result should contain the letter entered in the textbox at any position in it, what I need is that the items returned by the query should have the text in textbox as first lest characteres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var searchValue = textBox1.Text.Trim();//you can add a ToUpper();
        var qry = (from p in dc.Products
                   where p.ProductName.StartsWith(searchValue);//you can add a ToUpper() to p.ProductName
                   select p).ToList();
        productDataGridView.DataSource = qry;
    }
```

Comment: @AlphaBird, by the way I think you code would have work with just `Substring(0, aa)`

Answer (score 0):

never and I say never use == to compare 2 strings
always use equals() or contains()
if you are comparing 2 strings most likely u will get a false eventhough the 2 strings look exactly the same.
The difference is that each of the string point to a different object. Basically everytime u make a string it creates a new object of the class String.

Comment: Could you please give an example with equals() using my initial question, I have tried it and datagrid is returned empty when filling textbox.

Comment: This is only true in java. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659097/c-string-equals-vs

Comment: well I switched shorty to c# from java. I have never tested this theory in c#. the link proves your point I stand corrected ;)