# How to find item in the list using item

Tags: c#, list

I am having list using the following item below

```
Id CategoryName

1  CinemaGallery,CinemaEvents,Cinema

2  CinemaNews, Cinema, CinemaTrailer

3  TamilCinemaNews, TamilCinema, Tamil
```

Now i have to split each categoryname and have to find the list that contains each category. For example I have to find the list that has Categoryname only `Cinema` or only `CinemaEvents` or only `TamilCinema`.

I used Contains method but it returns all the list which has Cinema in the each string.

Could you please help me?

Comment: An example of what you've tried so far would help.

Comment: What if the list contains multiple entries "Cinema"?

Comment: Not a bad question after the Edit

Comment: you may show expected output on your example criteria, This will make the question more clear

Comment: please check my edited question above

Answer (score 1):

Then you just have to use `==` instead of `IndexOf` or `Contains`:

```
var cinema = list.First(i => i.Name == "Cinema");
```

or using `List.Find`:

```
var cinema = list.Find(i => i.Name == "Cinema");
```

You can use `Enumerable.Where` or [`List.FindAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z.aspx) to find all matching elements:

```
var cinemas = list.FindAll(i => i.Name == "Cinema");
cinemas = list.Where(i => i.Name == "Cinema").ToList();
```

**Edit** (to take your last edit into account):

```
var allCinemasOnly = list
        .Where(l => l.All(cat => cat.CategoryName == "Cinema"))
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
foreach (string s in myList)
{
    if (s.Contains("Cinema") && !s.Contains("Cinema "))
    {
        //do comething with 's'
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just equality? http://stackoverflow.com/q/1659097/1689451

Comment: I'm assuming that each line he gave is what's contained in the list entries. And by the looks of the most recent edit I may have been correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<string> yourNewList = yourList.Select(x => x = "Cinema").ToList();
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.Where(x => x == "Cinema")`?

Comment: @MatthewRz: No, it should be `.Where(x => x.Name == "Cinema").First()`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ahh, I didn't see his update.

Comment: @MatthewRz: That was true before his updates, now he needs `.Where(x => x.Name == "Cinema").ToList()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do like this ..

var itm = list.Find(a =>
        {
            var s = a.Split(Convert.ToChar(",")).ToList();
            return s.Exists(b => b == "Cinema");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var list = yourlist.Where(a => a == "Cinema").ToArray();
```