# Using == or .Equals() for bool comparison

Tags: c#

I was reviewing some code, and I found something that looked like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public bool IsEditable { get; set; }

    public void HandleInput()
    {
        if (IsEditable.Equals(false))
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I know, `(IsEditable.Equals(false))` is identical to `(IsEditable == false)` (and also the same as `(!IsEditable)`).

Besides personal preference, is there any difference at all between `.Equals()` and `==`, **specifically when used to compare `bool`s**?

Comment: Just speculation: maybe it was ported from Java where `==` and `.Equals` have different meanings? EDIT: or as Mike Petty pointed out, perhaps it was written by a long-time Java developer who is used to writing `Equals` normally.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [C#: String.Equals vs. ==](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1659097/299327)

Comment: When `x` is an expression of type (non-nullable) `bool`, I never compare to `true` or `false`. It is easier to use just `x` instead of `x == true` or `x.Equals(true)` or `x != false`, and easier to use `!x` instead of `x == false` or `x.Equals(false)` or `x != true`. And so on. With _two_ non-constant bool expressions, I use the C# built-in operators rather than `Equals`, for example I would use `x == y` or `x != y` (sometimes even `x ^ y`). However with *nullable* booleans, for example `bool? z`, I might use `z == false`. It has the same value as `(z.HasValue && !z.Value)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Equals` way appears to be significantly slower - roughly 2.7 times in debug mode, and more than seven times in release mode.

Here is my quick and dirty benchmark:

```
public static void Main() {
    bool a = bool.Parse("false");
    bool b = bool.Parse("true");
    bool c = bool.Parse("true");
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    const int Max = 1000000000;
    int count = 0;
    sw.Start();
    // The loop will increment count Max times; let's measure how long it takes
    for (int i = 0; i != Max; i++) {
        count++;
    }
    sw.Stop();
    var baseTime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    sw.Start();
    count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i != Max; i++) {
        if (a.Equals(c)) count++;
        if (b.Equals(c)) count++;
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds - baseTime);
    sw.Reset();
    count = 0;
    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i != Max; i++) {
        if (a==c) count++;
        if (b==c) count++;
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds - baseTime);
    sw.Reset();
    count = 0;
    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i != Max; i++) {
        if (!a) count++;
        if (!b) count++;
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds - baseTime);
}
```

Running this produces the following results:

#### In debug mode

```
8959
2950
1874
```

#### In release mode

```
5348
751
7
```

`Equals` appears to be the slowest. There appears to be little difference between `==` and `!=`. However, `if (!boolExpr)` appears to be the clear winner.

Comment: See my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13615362/128709) for the explanation why Equals is the slowest.

Answer (score 12):

This is mostly a readability issue.  I'd normally use `==` because that's what I'm used to looking at.

Specifically with bools, you don't have to compare them at all

```
if(!IsEditable)
```

will suffice

although, Sometimes I myself do write things like `if (val == false)` just to be extra sure that i don't misread it when i have to modify the code.

Comment: I agree with val == false rather than !val as it's much easier to read and when you've been looking at code all day long and are bug hunting your eyes easily miss the ! symbol. Yes, it's more characters to type blah blah, but the compiled version is the same, which is what counts.

Answer (score 12):

In fact, for basic types such as `int`, `bool` etc. there is a difference between calling `Equals()` and `==` due to the fact that the CIL has instructions for handling such types. Calling `Equals()` forces boxing of the value and making a virtual method call, whereas usage of `==` leads to usage of a single CIL instruction.

`!value` and `value == false` is actually the same, at least in Microsoft's C# compiler bundled with .NET 4.0.

Hence, the comparisons within the following methods

```
public static int CompareWithBoxingAndVirtualMethodCall(bool value)
{
    if (value.Equals(false)) { return 0; } else { return 1; }
}

public static int CompareWithCILInstruction(bool value)
{
    if (value == false) { return 0; } else { return 1; }
    if (!value) { return 0; } else { return 1; } // comparison same as line above
}
```

will compile to to the following CIL instructions:

```
// CompareWithBoxingAndVirtualMethodCall

ldarga.s 'value'
ldc.i4.0
call instance bool [mscorlib]System.Boolean::Equals(bool) // virtual method call
brfalse.s IL_000c // additional boolean comparison, jump for if statement

// CompareWithCILInstruction

ldarg.0
brtrue.s IL_0005 // actual single boolean comparison, jump for if statement
```

Comment: This potentially impacts performance (and it will almost always be by a negligible amount) but won't ever impact the result of the expression.  (Just for those types listed.)

Answer (score 2):

If you decompile System.Boolean and look at it, It's Equals overloads are defined thus:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
  if (!(obj is bool))
    return false;
  else
    return this == (bool) obj;
}

public bool Equals(bool obj)
{
  return this == obj;
}
```

I would like to think the C# compiler's optimizer and the .Net JIT compiler would be smart enough to inline these, at least for release/optimized compilations, making them exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference - at least in .NET 4.8 - I believe the reason is because of the boxing described in [Oliver Hanappi's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614839/using-or-equals-for-bool-comparison#answer-13615362) answer:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     object lhs = true;
     object rhs = true;
 
     Console.WriteLine($"Are Equal - {(lhs == rhs ? "Yes" : "No")}"); // Outputs no
     Console.WriteLine($"Are Equal - {(lhs.Equals(rhs) ? "Yes" : "No")}"); // Outputs yes
     Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In this case, with bools,  it doesn't make any difference, however with other built-in non reference types it can.

`==` allows for conversions of types if it can  `.Equals` won't

Comment: There are quite a few differences between `operator ==` and `Equals` in the general case, none of which apply to `bool`.  The one reason that you gave isn't one of those many reasons; `operator ==` doesn't convert anything.

Comment: try doing  1 == 1.0    it will do that comparison just fine,  but 1.Equals(1.0)  won't...

Comment: `operator ==` isn't converting anything.  It's effectively just a method, like any other.  It's signature is simply specific enough such that no overload of it will match `1 == 1.0` exactly, it will only match `operator == (double first, double second)` and the compiler will notice that as the closest match, and also that there is an implicit conversion from `int` to `double`.  If you used a method with a signature `Equals(double first, double second)` and then called `Equals(1, 1.0)` it would compile and return true.

Comment: try again, this time when explaining it doesn't convert anything, don't say that it converts something to get its job done.

Comment: `operator ==` *doesn't* convert anything though, that's my point.  The C# compiler is doing the conversion as a result of finding the proper overload.  If the signature of `Equals` didn't already cover *everything* (being object and object) it would do the same.  Using `operator ==` *allows the compiler to perform implicit conversions while `Equals` does not*, but the operator itself still isn't doing any converting.  It's an important difference.  There is no code, whatsoever, within the definition of `operator ==` that is converting any types.

Comment: yes...  fair enough, I rephrased so not to imply that the operator does it.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the following quote [Taken from here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/29/when-should-i-use-and-when-should-i-use-equals.aspx):

> The Equals method is just a virtual one defined in System.Object, and
>   overridden by whichever classes choose to do so. The == operator is an
>   operator which can be overloaded by classes, but which usually has
>   identity behaviour.
>
> For reference types where == has not been overloaded, it compares
>   whether two references refer to the same object - which is exactly
>   what the implementation of Equals does in System.Object.

So in short, `Equals` is really just doing a == anyways.

Answer (score -1):

`==` is always better than `.Equals`. In the case of integer comparison, `==` runs faster than `.Equals`. In the below test, the elapsed time using `==` 157, while for `.Equals` the elapsed time is 230.

```
class Program
 {        
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Program programObj = new Program();
            programObj.mymethod();
            programObj.mynextmethod();

    }
    void mynextmethod()
    {
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < 60000000; i++)
        {
            int j = 0;
            if (i.Equals(j))

                j = j + 1;
        }
        watch.Stop();
        var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine("Time take in method" + elapsedMs);


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    void mymethod()
    {
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < 60000000; i++)
        {
            int j = 0;
            if (i == j)

                j = j + 1;
        }
        watch.Stop();
        var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine("Time take in method" + elapsedMs);
    }
}
```

Comment: This *isn't* an integer comparison.  It's a boolean comparison.