# Elapsed time is not giving me expected result

Tags: c#, elapsedtime

I receive a string containing "1" every few seconds. I am trying to get the elapsed time between the received string and the next one to return the elapsed time. I am doing something wrong. The result I get is 0 and the string is instead updated exactly every second, so I should read 1. I am quite sure there is a mistake in the logic but I cannot see where it is. This should run for hours and update every time I get an update on the string "giriRicevuti".

```
class Rpm
{
    public void CalcolaRPM(string giriRicevuti, out long RPM)
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();

        if (giriRicevuti == "1")
        {
            stopWatch.Stop();
        }
            long duration = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            RPM =(duration/1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: When do you call the method?

Comment: Your method starts a stopwatch and then immediately measures how long the stopwatch has been running -- which is obviously not for a very long time, because you just started the stopwatch.

Comment: @dtb, should stop when I get the next "1". That is what I am trying to achieve. I have put there a condition to stop. But obviously isn't working.

Comment: @BernhardPoiss every time I get a message from serial port containing "1".

Comment: use Equals method to compare. string.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659097/c-string-equals-vs

Comment: The scope of `stopWatch` is the `CalcolaRPM` method.  It isn't even static.  You need to rearrange things so that it persists from one call to the next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to your comments and advices I ended up with this solution. I also simplified the method using a return and some floating variables to get more accuracy.
This one is working for my app.

```
class Turns
{
    static DateTime prevTimeInstance = DateTime.Now;
    static float RPM = 0;

    public float Counts(int getTurn)
    {
        TimeSpan currentTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
        if (getTurn.Equals(1))
        {
            currentTimeSpan = DateTime.Now.Subtract(prevTimeInstance);
            prevTimeInstance = DateTime.Now;
            if (currentTimeSpan.TotalSeconds != 0)
                RPM = 60.0f / (float)currentTimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
        }
        return RPM;
    }
}
```

I would like to thank Mattew for the big help he gave me.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to keep a stopwatch around outside the `CalcolaRPM()` method if you want to time things *inbetween* calls to it.

The easiest thing to do is to add it as a private field in the class.

Another problem is that when `giriRicevuti` isn't "1" you will need to return the last known RPM - we can solve that by keeping the last known RPM in a private field too.

And yet another issue is that the very first time the RPM is calculated, it cannot be accurate because there is no preceeding time to compare it with. We will solve this by returning `-1` until we have a correct time to report.

And next, you are calculating the elapsed RPM as an integer calculation. Now imagine if things were slightly out so the elapsed time was always 999 milliseconds. Only a millisecond out, but your calculation of RPM = 999/1000 would result in zero.

You have several options, but the most likely are:

- Return a double instead.
- Round the value to the nearest RPM.

I went for the rounding. The RPM calculation was incorrect, so I'm correcting that at the same time:

```
lastRPM = (int) Math.Round(60000.0/((int) stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
```

Putting that altogether, here's a compilable test program (console app):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

namespace Demo
{
    class Rpm
    {
        private Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        private int lastRPM = -1;

        // RPM will be -1 until we have received two "1"s       

        public int CalcolaRPM(string giriRicevuti)
        {
            if (giriRicevuti == "1")
            {
                if (stopWatch.IsRunning)
                    lastRPM = (int) Math.Round(60000.0/((int) stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));

                stopWatch.Restart();
            }

            return lastRPM;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        void run()
        {
            test(900);
            test(1000);
            test(1100);
            test(500);
            test(200);
        }

        void test(int interval)
        {
            Rpm rpm = new Rpm();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(interval);
                rpm.CalcolaRPM("0");
                rpm.CalcolaRPM("1").Print();
                rpm.CalcolaRPM("2");
            }
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }

    static class DemoUtil
    {
        public static void Print(this object self)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(self);
        }

        public static void Print(this string self)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(self);
        }

        public static void Print<T>(this IEnumerable<T> self)
        {
            foreach (var item in self) Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The initial calculation will tend to be inaccurate since the stopwatch was started at an arbitrary time.

Comment: I guess we should return -1 for the first calculation, since that will always be inaccurate. I'll update with that.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, thanks man but RPM is still 0 even if the string giriRicevuti gets update every 1 second. I have checked it with a break point. Moreover I have a filter on the incoming serial messages that detects the "1" and pass it to this method, so there are not other type of values passed to it.

Comment: @FeliceM I have one last issue to fix then, haha. :) I'm updating now, be a couple of mins

Comment: @HABO, I need to measure the RPM of a motor that is running at 5 to 10 turns per minute. Shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, LOL, it is giving -1 now. But we are on the good direction. :-)

Comment: @FeliceM - Hang on.  RPM is usually revolutions per minute.  Elapsed milliseconds divided by 1000 (using integer arithmetic) isn't going to give you the right units.  Don't you want `60000/elapsed ms`?

Comment: @HABO, lets try to get something out then we fix the math.

Comment: @HABO Yeah I think that needs sorted too :)

Comment: You can do away with `isFirstTime` by not starting the `stopWatch` when it is created.  Use `stopWatch.IsRunning` to determine if it is the first pass.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, great job Mattew but keeps retuning always -1. I have also changed the timing, now the variable is updated every 1.5 seconds but still I get only -1.

Comment: @Hang on I'm going to have to actually compile a test program!

Comment: @MatthewWatson, no problem, really appreciated. It is few hours that I am going stupid with this. So I fully understand.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, I added a stopWatch.Start(); to get it going and now is working. Thanks for your support. I am getting very inaccurate readings but this is not your problem. I think is the elapsed time method.