# how to check if sources of two images are same in Windows Phone 7 and C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How can I check if two images have same source in wp7 C#?
I am doing this but it's not working.

```
if(image1.source.tostring()==image2.source.tostring()){}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any easy way to do that. [ImageSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an abstract class and can be anything therefore it is hard to compare. However the most likely implementation is [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). So you can check of its type and if it is BitmapImage or [IUriContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.iuricontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can cast it and compare the [BaseUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.iuricontext.baseuri%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing references, to compare values...

```
if(image1.source.ToString().Equals(image2.source.ToString())) {}
```

Comment: thanks but when the source are different , this code make the condition true !

Comment: if you want to inverse put `not` symbol in front of condition (`!`) - if(!image1...)

Comment: Are you both joking? ToString() method returns string type, and (string) == (string) must have [same result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659097/c-string-equals-vs) as (string).Equals(string)

Comment: thats why it always make the condition true . Thanks pavel but how can i do this ??

Comment: There is more details needed. It will be great to see your XAML with more codebehind (c#).

Comment: thanks pavel , but i found the solution ........
BitmapImage bm1 = (BitmapImage)image1.Source;
BitmapImage bm2 = (BitmapImage)image2.Source;

bool same =(string.Compare(bm1.UriSource.AbsoluteUri,bm2.UriSource.AbsoluteUri) == 0);
share|improve this answer

Comment: Just saw you comment. Basically it's what I said but keep in mind that source is not necessary Bitmapimage.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare both of the images with the help of BitmapImage

```
BitmapImage image1= new BitmapImage(new Uri("your first image relative path", UriKind.Relative))

BitmapImage image2= new BitmapImage(new Uri("your second image relative path", UriKind.Relative))

if(image1==image2)
{
MessageBox.show("Image matched.");
}
else
{
MessageBox.Show("Not matched.");
}
```