# Using == or .Equals() on nulls and string.Empty

Tags: c#, null, string

In reference to using `.Equals()` or `==` on strings, here is a question in regards to checking for `string.Empty` and `null` objects.

In comparing `string.Empty` and `null` objects, should I use `==` or should I use `.Equals()`?

```
// Add vars to instance variables
for (int i = 0; i < paramFirstList.Count; i++)
{
    // if the key is null, replace it
    // with a "null" string
    if (paramFirstList[i] == null)
    {
        _firstList.Add("null");
    }
    else if (paramFirstList[i] == string.Empty)
    {
        _firstList.Add("empty");
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

P.S. I understand it's better to store `null` and `string.Empty` as their object types, but for this particular purpose, it is in my requirements to store them as a string representation :).

P.P.S. Added hungarian notation for the sake of question clarity

Comment: The question is not clear, first you're talking of `String.Empty` and `null` but then you are adding `"empty"` and `"null"`. Also you `P.S` is even more confusing.

Comment: @Tim: I believe that the PS is answering your question. He is saying that rather than storing `null` he is storing `"null"` and while he knows he should store them as object types (ie `null`) he is storing them as a string representation (ie `"null"`). His checks are workign on string.empty and null though so I'm not sure why you are worrying about what he is putting in the list.

Comment: I knew someone would mention storing the string representation of `null` and/or `string.Empty` so I put the disclaimer there that I know what I am doing, and what I am doing is on purpose.

Comment: Well, What's that `firstList` type? `List<string>` or `List<object>`?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Is that relevant? the thing we are looking at is, as the title says, "Using == or .Equals() on nulls and string.Empty". What he is putting in the list and what type it is seems irrelevant to me...

Comment: Both are `List<string>`

Comment: @Chris Yes relevant. If it is `List<Object>` then `==` operator would fail.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. I misread you as asking about `_firstList` for some reason.

Comment: @Chris Nevermind, confusions due to poor naming conventions :p

Comment: Should I change the way the names work? It seems to be confusing some people. The `_firstList` is an instance variable while `firstList` is the input for this constructor.

Comment: Yes I suggest you better change names to avoid further confusions; not only in your question in production code too

Comment: IMHO this is okay (and quite common) to prefix private class members with an underscore. It just wasn't easy to figure out in a SO question context. :) In any case, given the question it's not that much important.

Comment: What naming scheme to differentiate between an input parameter vs. an instance variable?

Comment: For the sake of making sample code as easy to understand as possible, drop the underscore for your instance variable and just append "Param" to your parameter variable name. Of course, don't do that in production code. ;) Again, though: this is hardly an issue. The question is about using Equals or ==.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure about using Hungarian Notation in my production code ;-).

Comment: Keep in mind that if you try to call `s.Equals(null)` when `s` is in fact `null` you'll end up with an `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always favor == over `Equals`. The latter is a method of the base `Object` type which in this case will do useless casting.

If you mean to check whether a `string` value is null or empty, use [`String.IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. If, instead, you need to act differently if it's one or the other, then do this:

```
if (value == null)
{
    //do stuff
}
else if (value == string.Empty)
{
    // do other stuff
}
```

**EDIT:**

As pointed out in the comments there *is* an overloaded `Equals` method on a `string` that receives a `string` parameter. Still, I think you should take the habit of using ==. It just reads better IMHO.

Comment: "The latter is a method of the base Object type." Just to make it explicit, it *is* overriden (so it's a value comparision too) and there is also an overload which takes a `String` parameter.

Comment: Thanks, added an additional precision.

Comment: There is no boxing/unboxing involved in strings, because string is a reference type

Comment: I am rather still confused -- it's a better idea to use `value == string.Empty` than `value.Equals(string.Empty)`?

Comment: @Georg you are absolutely right, I tend to forget strings are references not values. :)

Comment: @theGreenCabbage as I said: favor ==.

Comment: That's just.. so against what I learned, haha. I've always read from Stack that for string comparisons, you should use `.Equals()` versus `==`, since `==` checks object reference while `.Equals()` checks string equality. This question is to clarify that, I suppose.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage This holds for many languages like e.g. Java, but C# knows operator overloading and indeed, == is overloaded for string. Thus, there is absolutely no difference between == and Equals in C#, besides readability and understandability

Comment: Ah thank you! You're entirely right -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659097/c-string-equals-vs

Comment: I would say there *is* a difference: with the == operator you still can compare two null strings. Equals will require that at least one instance is non null. ;)

Comment: Well -- thanks for the awesome discussion guys! Solved my issue and answered my question. Adieu.

Answer (score 3):

If you're concerned about `null`, you should use [`string.IsNullOrEmpty()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx), or perhaps [`string.IsNullOrWhitespace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx)

Comment: @Chris I had the feeling this was just sample code.

Comment: Surely if that is the case you should still answer the question not some other question that you think he meant?

Comment: @Chris but that is no problem either, because comparing against null is no longer necessary he could do sth like `if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringVar)) { if(stringVar.Equals(string.Empty)) { .....` so one could catch that case too seperately

Comment: @DrCopyPaste: Yes, there are ways around it but the title of the question says its about using the merits of `==` vs `.Equals`. An answer that doesn't cover either of those for the uses in question is surely not even close to answering the question...

Comment: I would note that I have no problem with recommending use of this method as an additional note, I just don't believe it is a valid answer (though voting would seem to disagree with me)

Comment: Yep! Detecting separately is important.