# Component does not exist in the current context - C#

Tags: c#, windows, scope, store

I have this code (the problem lines have comments above them):

```
private async void btn_loginAdmin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // 'txt_adminId' does not exist in the current context.
            if (txt_adminId.Text = "root")
            {
                // 'txt_adminPw' does not exist in the current context.
                if (txt_adminPw.Password = "password")
                {
                    var msg_login = new MessageDialog("Logged in!");
                    await msg_login.ShowAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    var msg_login = new MessageDialog("Wrong password!");
                    await msg_login.ShowAsync();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var msg_login = new MessageDialog("Wrong combo!");
                await msg_login.ShowAsync();
            }
        }
```

I have always had that problem with C#. I don't know what it means. But I'm sure that in this file's .xaml, those 2 text boxes exist.

- This is a Windows Store C# program.

EDIT:

Here's the output:

```
1>C:\Database\GH3_WSE\GH3_WSE\login_admin.xaml.cs(119,17,119,42): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'
1>C:\Database\GH3_WSE\GH3_WSE\login_admin.xaml.cs(121,21,121,54): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'
```

Comment: Why is your Click handler marked async?

Comment: To make the MessageDialog work. I tried removing them but it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: I see. No experience with WP, but seems to me connected with async and threads. Using MVVM could help you here perhaps.

Comment: I hear that a lot. But I don't exactly know how to start with it.

Comment: @Wix are you sure you have a valid check here `txt_adminId.Text = "root"` ? Shouldn't it be `==`? Same on this line `if (txt_adminPw.Password = "password")`

Comment: @SJD I've been so soaked up with COBOL right now that I forgot the fact that in C, '=' and '==' have different meanings. This answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: So 'txt_adminId' does exist in the current context?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `x:Class` on `xaml` page has the exact name of your `.cs` class.

It should be like:

```
x:Class = "ProjectName.C#ClassName"
```

Comment: They're exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot twice the `=` operator on the following lines:

```
if (txt_adminId.Text = "root")
```

should be

```
if (txt_adminId.Text == "root")
```

and also on this line

```
if (txt_adminPw.Password = "password")
```

So, you might want to write this:

```
private async void btn_loginAdmin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // 'txt_adminId' does not exist in the current context.

            if (txt_adminId.Text == "root")
            {
                // 'txt_adminPw' does not exist in the current context.
                if (txt_adminPw.Password == "password")
                {
                    var msg_login = new MessageDialog("Logged in!");
                    await msg_login.ShowAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    var msg_login = new MessageDialog("Wrong password!");
                    await msg_login.ShowAsync();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var msg_login = new MessageDialog("Wrong combo!");
                await msg_login.ShowAsync();
            }
        }
```

Also, I would recommend to use `String.Equals` instead of `==`, because you would like to compare values rather than reference. Note that `String.Equals` compares proper values while `==` also takes into consideration their references.

See: [Why would you use String.Equals over ==?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659097/why-would-you-use-string-equals-over)