# How do I compare the value of string array?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have declared a string array and I want to compare with name given by user,

```
string[] MasterList = new string[] {
  "Askay", "Puram", "Raman", "Srinivasa",
  "Gopal", "Rajesh", "Anju", "Nagara",
};

string YourName;
Console.WriteLine("Enter your name: ");
YourName = Console.ReadLine();

for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    a = String.Compare(MasterList[i], YourName);
    Console.WriteLine("Your name is not among the list")
}
```

The resulting output is not what I am expecting, any ideas how I can go about it?

Comment: Why use `i<5` when you have more than 5 indices in your array? Why not `MasterList.Length`?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile and you havent told what you expect. But simple: `if(!MasterList.Contains(YourName)){...}` instead of the for-loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
bool found = false;
foreach (string s in MasterList)
{
    if(s == YourName)
    found = true;
}
if(found)
    Console.WriteLine("Your name is among the list");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Your name is not among the list");
```

Comment: Can people who are downvoting please give some comments to @Peter who is a relatively new user :)

Comment: @garfbradaz if Peter cannot work out what is wrong with his answer there is always [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thats what I mean @Jamiec - that is helpful, giving a link for guidance (I was trying to find it myself to post) - kudo! :)

Comment: Comparing strings with `==` operators can yield unpredictable results (I did not downvote).  You're referencing to see if it's the _exact same object_ (which strings often are not, regardless of contents).

Comment: @gravity see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659097/why-would-you-use-string-equals-over

Comment: @gravity Strings work differently in C# than they do in Java. `==` is safe.

Comment: Thanks man...it worked just as i wanted it! thanks @Peter Meadley

Comment: At very least  break out of the loop when youve found the item.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx) method?

Add the following line to your using directives first:

```
using System.Linq;
```

And then, remove the for loop and use the following line instead:

```
if (!MasterList.Contains(YourName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your name is not among the list")
}
```

Comment: I think using `Contains` here is not safe, even it `Contains`, still may not be the name, should be fully matched

Answer (score 2):

Why not `Contains`?

```
  string[] MasterList = new string[] {
    "Askay", "Puram", "Raman", "Srinivasa",
    "Gopal", "Rajesh", "Anju", "Nagara",
  };

  Console.WriteLine("Enter your name: ");
  string YourName = Console.ReadLine();

  // StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase if you want to ignore case
  // MasterList.Contains(YourName) if you want case sensitive 
  if (!MasterList.Contains(YourName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    Console.WriteLine("Your name is not among the list")
```