# Get IndexOf if next line equals text

Tags: c#, indexof

I need to get the index of a specific line in a `List<string>` if the next line equals the variable

```
List:
Chapter
1
He 
Was
Chapter
2
She
Is
```

I want the IndexOf "Chapter" where the next line equals 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var index=GetIndex(list,"Chapter","2");

public int GetIndex( List<string> list, string current, string next)
{
    var previous = string.Empty;
    var index = 0;
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        if (item == next && previous == current) return index-1;
        index++;
        previous = item;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The thing is, using `IndexOf`, you get the [first occurrence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof?view=net-6.0). Instead, you could check for all occurrences of "Chapter", check if the value of the following index is `2`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; i++){
    if ("Chapter".Equals(list[i]) && "2".Equals(list[i+1]))
        answerIndex = i;
```

Comment: Side note: `"Chapter".Equals(list[i])` as well as `"2".Equals(list[i+1])` will do even if some of `list` items are `null`

Comment: "Most important thing is to not use == when comparing strings." Hun? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1659107/1043380

Comment: @gunr2171 Apologies, must've mixed it up with Java!