# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help converting type - cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871530/help-converting-type-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-string-to-bool)

I've got this code:

```
private double Price;
private bool Food;
private int count;
private decimal finalprice;

public void Readinput()
{
    Console.Write("Unit price:  ");
    Price = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Food item y/n:  ");
    Food = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Count:  ");
    count = Console.ReadLine();
}

private void calculateValues()
{
    finalprice = Price * count;
}
```

and get the following errors:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'
>
> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'double'
>
> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'
>
> Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'decimal'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I know what it means but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Hey, why the votes down?

Comment: I don't think this question deserves that many downvotes.Giving him directions would be much more helpful.

Comment: @ivowiblo: I didn't vote down, but I imagine this is because the answer to this question is so simple that downvoters think the OP didn't try himself before posting. Hard to say they are wrong.

Comment: I think the idea is to help and give directions. Answering with a link to a duplicated question is enough.

Comment: @Styne666 that's not an exact duplicate.

Comment: @Esoteric You're correct; comment rescinded.

Answer (score 25):

Use `bool.Parse` or `bool.TryParse` method to convert string value to `boolean`.

```
Price = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Food =bool.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

You can't convert "y" or "n" value to boolean instead your have to receive value as a string and if it is "y" then store `true`, `false` otherwise.

```
Console.Write("Food item y/n:  ");
string answer = Console.ReadLine();
if(answer=="y")
   Food=true;
else
   Food=false;
```

Or (suggestion of @Mr-Happy)

```
 Food = answer == "y"
```

You need to specify explicit cast while calculating `finalprice`.

```
private void calculateValues()
{
   // convert double result into decimal.
    finalprice =(decimal) Price * count;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to use `Food = answer == "y";` though

Answer (score 5):

You have to convert what you read from the console (which is a string) to the actual type using the static class Convert. For example:

```
Console.Write("Count:  ");
count = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

This crashes if the argument given can't be converted, but this is not your primary problem right now, so let's keep it simple.

Answer (score 2):

```
Console.Write("Unit price:  ");
double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Price);

Console.Write("Food item y/n:  ");
bool.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Food);

Console.Write("Count:  ");
int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out count);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private double Price;
private bool Food;
private int count;
private decimal finalprice;

public void Readinput()
{
    Console.Write("Unit price:  ");
    double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Price);

    Console.Write("Food item y/n:  ");
    bool.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Food);

    Console.Write("Count:  ");
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out count);
}

private void calculateValues()
{
    finalprice = Price * count;
}
```

Comment: Use of tryparse is useless if you don't catch the result. How do you know something is wrong ? Either use the classic Parse with the throw of an exception, or wrap the tryparse with a `if(!tryparse(..)) error handling`

Comment: Indeed it would be better when you catch the errors but the application will nog crash and use the default value for double = 0, bool = false and int = 0.

Comment: So it depends on the business requirement... should the program inform the user he typed something wrong ? I think the answer is yes. The answer should be yes. My opinion is that silent errors are more dangerous (it can leads to problems later) than a application crash.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the `Console.ReadLine()` calls in the appropriate parser functions, since (unlike PHP, for example) C# is a static typed language, additionally only conversions which are guaranteed to be both safe and lossless can be done implicitly:

```
Price = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Food item y/n:  ");
// I think you want the user to type in "y", "Y", "n" or "N", right?
Food = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper() == "Y";

Console.Write("Count:  ");
count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

And in your calculation method, you have to explicitly convert the resulting double into a decimal since C# doesn't support implicit conversion between fixed point and floating point values:

```
finalprice = (decimal)(Price * count);
```