# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Display a string value as Bool

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am hoping for some help.  I have a string value - will be coming back as Y or N.  On a page I would like to convert this and display it as a readonly checkbox on the page.

I have tried

```
@Html.CheckboxFor( model => Convert.ToBoolean(MyString))
```

but it does not like that.  Has anyone got any ideas how I can acheive this.  Do I need to do a convert to bool on my string in my c# controller page?

Comment: Do you think Convert to Boolean would evaluate `"Y"` [as what](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8895568/570150) ? Least you could do is `Convert.ToBoolean(MyString =="Y")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a field on your Model that does the conversion. `CheckBoxFor` expects an `Expression<Func<TModel, Boolean>>` because it needs to know property name based on expression.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you storing it as a string with a Y/N value?

I don't know if you can do that with CheckboxFor() - you may need to use a regular checkbox instead and just make sure that it is disabled and the value is `MyString == "Y"` which should return true or false based on your storage option.

More sensible, though, would be to change the Y/N to true/false on the way into the database, which would then allow you to use the data more practically.

Comment: Unfortunately its a 3rd party who will ne sending the data back to me and they store Y/N as a string

Answer (score 0):

What about:

> @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.MyString=="Y", new { @Readonly =
>   "readonly" })

This may work.

Answer (score 0):

This simple way works fine

```
@Html.CheckBox("IsActive", Model.MyString == "Y" ? true : false)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string stringValue = "true";
bool value;
bool.TryParse(stringValue, out value);
```

or in ASP.NET

```
@Html.CheckboxFor( model => C bool.Parse(model.MyString))
```