# Cannot implicitly convert type bool to string when trying to read a line from a file. c #

Tags: c#, file, listbox, streamreader, ioexception

I am getting an error and I don't know why because I am not really good with c# and I am following a guide and it looks very similar. So when I assign my str variable to the StreamReader variable, inputFile, I get an error that says I cannot implicitly convert type bool to string.

```
if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        StreamReader inputFile = File.OpenText(openFile.FileName);

                        String str;

                        // Getting the error here
                        while (str = inputFile.ReadLine() != null)
                        {
                            str = inputFile.ReadLine();
                            listBox1.Items.Add(str);
                        }

                    } else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Canceled");
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
while ((str = inputFile.ReadLine()) != null)
```

Hope helps,

Answer (score 1):

It becomes easier to see the problem when you add brackets:

```
while (str = (inputFile.ReadLine() != null) )
```

The compiler is evaluating the result of `inputFile.ReadLine() != null` which is a bool, then trying to assign it to `str`

Try to change the default order of evaluation by adding parenthesis as follows:

```
while ( (str = inputFile.ReadLine()) != null )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try parenthesis around the part assigning str

while ((str = inputFile.ReadLine()) != null)

Answer (score 0):

When all you want is just to read a file, try using `File.ReadAllLines` instead of `StreamReader` and you'll get consize

```
   if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     listBox1.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(openFile.FileName));
   else
     MessageBox.Show("Canceled");
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the operator precedence. The **[!=](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tz250sf.aspx)** operator has [higher precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) than the **[=](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx)**, so

```
inputFile.ReadLine() != null
```

will be evaluated first and the result (bool) will be assigned to variable str (string).

You received an error because in C# you [cannot implicitly convert type string to bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895547/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-string-to-bool).