# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help converting type - cannot implicitly convert type ‘string’ to ‘bool’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871530/help-converting-type-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-string-to-bool)

I am very new to the language n I am not a good programmer. This code is giving me error:

> cannot implicitly convert type int to bool.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
Can some tell me what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated n any recomendation would also help.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;

   namespace ConsoleApplication2
   {
     class mysteryVal
  {
   public const int limitOfGuess = 5;

  // Data member
    public int mystVal;
         private int numOfGuess ;
      private randomNumberMagnifier mag = new randomNumberMagnifier();

      public int randomMag(int num)
     {
        return num + mystVal;
      }

     // Instance Constructor
     public mysteryVal()
     {
        mystVal = 0;
         numOfGuess = 0;
            }

           public void game(int user)
          {
              int userInput = user;
               if (numOfGuess < limitOfGuess)
                     {
                  numOfGuess++;
                 if (userInput = mag.randomMagnifier())
                   {
                }
               }

           } 


           }
                }
```

Comment: where you declared the variable for limitOfGuess?

Comment: Different type, but same idea. Pay attention to *where* the error is - it'll walk you straight to the problem.

Comment: I declared it as a const. Right after the class declaration.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The line

```
if (userInput = mag.randomMagnifier())
```

should be

```
if (userInput == mag.randomMagnifier())
```

Answer (score 13):

Correct this:

```
if (userInput = mag.randomMagnifier())
```

to:

```
if (userInput == mag.randomMagnifier())
```

Here you are assigning the value in the `if` statement, which is wrong. You have to check the condition, for checking condition u have to use `"=="`.
`if` statement returns boolean values, and because you are assigning value here, it's giving the error.

Answer (score 3):

you should use == instead of = change: 
`Lif(userinput = mag.randommagnifier())` 
for

```
if(userinput == mag.randommagnifier())
```

Answer (score 3):

An if statement always contains an expression which evaluates to a boolean value. Your line

```
if (userInput = mag.randomMagnifier())
```

is not a `bool` which is what is causing the error. You probably meant

```
if (userInput == mag.randomMagnifier())
```

Answer (score 3):

The condition

```
userInput = mag.randomMagnifier()
```

needs to be

```
userInput == mag.randomMagnifier()
```

What you have is trying to assign the userInput value and then it tries to convert the int to bool. With C# this is not possible.