# I need to pull data from two separate listboxes for calculation

Tags: c#

```
if (fromListBox.SelectedIndex = 0 && toListBox.SelectedIndex = 1)
    input /= 12;
else if (fromListBox.SelectedIndex = 0 && toListBox.SelectedIndex = 2)
    input /= 36;
else if (fromListBox.SelectedIndex = 1 && toListBox.SelectedIndex = 0)
    input *= 12;
else if (fromListBox.SelectedIndex = 1 && toListBox.SelectedIndex = 2)
    input /= 3;
else if (fromListBox.SelectedIndex = 2 && toListBox.SelectedIndex = 0)
    input *= 36;
else if (fromListBox.SelectedIndex = 2 && toListBox.SelectedIndex = 1)
    input *= 3;
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I pull data from different listboxes for calculation?

This is a distance conversion application; user inputs a number into the `startingDistanceTextBox`, chooses what the measurement it is from the `fromListBox` and what they wish to convert it to from the `toListBox`; items are: inches, feet & yards(both listboxes). I am to display the conversion in a label.

Comment: What is `input`? What is the error? What is different from what you expect?

Comment: _"What am I doing wrong?"_ - you don't show what compiler error you get. Anyway, you want to compare (`==`), not assign (`=`).

Comment: Duplicate of [Help converting type - cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871530/help-converting-type-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-string-to-bool).

Comment: Error 1 Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int'.

Comment: -1 you failed to state in the question what was wrong with the code. If you ask about a compiler error you must give that error. The fact that you did not tells me that you don't read compiler errors at all. That's a bad habit that you must get past.

Comment: I'm new here; first day, first question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [*assignment operator*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx) `=`, you should use [`==`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) to compare your values

```
fromListBox.SelectedIndex == 0
```

Comment: If the solution worked, you should accept the answer. There should be a check mark underneath the answer score that you can click. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work