# C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool' error

Tags: c#, string, console, boolean

I'm new to C# I'm using microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 Windows Desktop edition and I was trying to make a quiz in which I ask the question and the user has to answer it so, here's the code and the error i get is 
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'" and this happens on the 2 if statements, I understand that a bool has either the value true or false however it's a string so why is it giving me this error? Any help should be appreciated.
**PS: I only included the part of the code in which i'm having the problem and this is the only code in the main class**

Heres the code:

```
 Start:
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Question 1: Test? type yes or no: ");
        String answer1 = Console.ReadLine();

        if (answer1 = "yes") {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Question 2: Test? type Yes or no");
        }
        else if (answer1 = "no")
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong, restarting program");
            goto Start;
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
            goto Start;
        }
```

Comment: you must type `==` not `=`

Comment: `=` assigns, `==` compares

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help converting type - cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871530/help-converting-type-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-string-to-bool)

Comment: i think its not good to answer a duplicate question. or at least one answer is enough

Comment: Please don't use `goto` statements as Terrance mentions below. They are harmful to the environment and to small fury animals

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in all of your if statements

```
if (answer1 = "yes")
```

should be

```
if (answer1 == "yes")
```

in c#, `=` is to assign a value, `==` is for comparison. Change it in all of your if statements and youll be fine

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this line:

```
if (answer1 = "yes") {
```

This will assign "yes" to answer1 first and then it's like

```
if(answer1) { // answer1 = "yes"
```

So now this will try to convert answer1 which is a string into a boolean, which the if statement requires. This does not work and throws the exception.

You'll have to do a comparison like this:

```
if(answer1 == "yes") {
```

or you could use equals like this:

```
if("yes".Equals(answer1)) {
```

and then do the same for the else if.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate reason is that `=` assigns, not compares values as `==` does.
So you can do

```
   if (answer1 == "yes") {
     ...
   }
```

However I'd prefer

```
  if (String.Equals(answer1, "yes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
    ...
  }
```

in case user chooses `"Yes"` or `"YES"` etc. as the answer

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx) `=` is the assignment operator in C#
[this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) `==` is a comparison operator in C#

for a full list of the operators in C# check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) out. As an asside I would generally recommend againt using [goto statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful)

All that being said your code should look something like this.

```
Start:
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Question 1: Test? type yes or no: ");
        String answer1 = Console.ReadLine();

        if (answer1 == "yes")
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Question 2: Test? type Yes or no");
        }
        else if (answer1 == "no")
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong, restarting program");
            goto Start;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
            goto Start;
        }
```