# Error: "cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool' "

Tags: c#, function, if-statement, return

Hi I have this code and it is keep saying that

> cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool' "

for every each "month = 1", "month = 2" etc... Can someone help?

```
public static string NumberToMonth(int month)
{
    if (month = 1)
        return "január";
    if (month = 2)
        return "február";
    if (month = 3)
        return "március";
    if (month = 4)
        return "április";
    if (month = 5)
        return "május";
    if (month = 6)
        return "június";
    if (month = 7)
        return "július";
    if (month = 8)
        return "augusztus";
    if (month = 9)
        return "szeptember";
    if (month = 10)
        return "október";
    if (month = 11)
        return "november";
    if (month = 12)
        return "december";        
    else
        return "";
```

Comment: `month ==` instead of `month =` for all your expressions.

Comment: Now I have realised omfg and i didnt realised that. Shame on me :( But thank You.

Comment: Completely orthogonal to the error message and your question but be aware that the globalization system in .NET can give you the names of the months without you hardcoding them in your program. In particular, your entire method can be replaced with this: `public static string NumberToMonth(int month) { return CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hu").GetMonthName(month); }`. If, on the other hand, you want the current regional setting month name, for display purposes to the user, simply use `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(month)` instead.

Comment: I realised that after I wrote my code but now I dont want to change it beause work was done into that code if you know what I mean.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error on if statement - cannot implicitly convert type to 'bool'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871530/error-on-if-statement-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-to-bool)

Answer (score 3):

Use `==` and not `=`.

1. The `=` is the [assigning operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/operators). In this line `if(month = 1)` you are assigning 1 into `month`.
2. The `==` is the [equality operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-comparison-operator) to check if two values/objects are
   equal.

Code should be:

```
if (month == 1)
        return "január";
```

When you use `=` then:

- You assign the value to `month` so now month contains the value 1.
- Then `month` is evaluated by the `if` statement.
- `if` statement basically gets `if(1)` which expects a `boolean` and not an `int`.
- There is no implicit conversion from `int` to `bool` and thus the compile 
  error.

---

Instead of writing your own method to retrieve month names use the built in: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7385985/6400526)

```
string monthName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(8);
```

Comment: You should also mention that an "assignment expression", such as `month = 1`, also *evaluates to* the assigned value, which is why there isn't a completely different compiler message here, the expression has the value 1, which is an int, thus the error message. To be honest I think the C# compiler guys could've done a better job of identifying the *probable* underlying problem here and giving hints.

Comment: It doesn't throw an exception though, as your answer suggests.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to your problem is already answered.

The reason for the message “cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool' ” is that `month = 1` is an expression that

1. assigns the value 1 to the variable `month`, and
2. returns the assigned value (`1`)

so the compiler sees `if (1)`, which means that there is an integer value where a boolean value was expected. So it complains about that.

Answer (score 1):

`=` is the assignment operator, so the expression `month = 1` is trying to assign the value of `1` to `month`.  What you want is `==`, which is the equality operator.  So you'd change your `if` conditions to be of the following form:

```
if (month == 1)
{
    return "január";
}
```

As to the reason for the error message, this is because you're performing an assignment, instead of a comparison.  In plain English, you're doing the following:

1. The value `1` is assigned to `month`.
2. The `if` condition now reads: `if 1 is true`.

So you're basically asking a question that cannot be answered.  Programmatically, what's happening is the following:

1. You're assigning the value of `1` to `month`.
2. The `if` condition then becomes `if (1)`, where `1` is an `int`, but a condition should evaluate to either `true` or `false` (i.e. a `bool`).

Therefore, the compiler is complaining because it expects a `bool`, but you're giving it an `int`.

Comment: Maybe explain why it says "cannot convert **int** to bool" when assigning.

Comment: @GillBates Done.  Sorry about that, the phone rang as I posted the answer.